# How can I send the jwt token to the next page after logged in successfully in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

### Intro

I am developing an login application using Nextjs on frontend and springboot on backend.

### Problem

I am able to login from the frontend which calls the loginAPI named  `/authenticate` developed in springboot and it is successfully returning the `authToken` which is I currently saving it in localstorage and then redirects to home (`/allcoupons`) page.

The home (`/allcoupons`)  page supposed to show the list of coupons which is fetched by another api developed in backend. Since this api is called in `getServerSideProps()` , I am unable to access the `authToken` and not able to pass it with the `getAllCoupons API`.

How can I send this authtoken to the home  (`/allcoupons`)  page after logged in successfully in Nextjs?

### Code

**login.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { FaUser } from "react-icons/fa";
import { AiFillInfoCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { RiLockPasswordFill } from "react-icons/ri";
import axios from "axios";


const Login = ({ reverse }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = (e, key) => {
    setCredentials((prevCredentials) => ({
      ...prevCredentials,
      [key]: e.target.value,
    }));
    //console.log(credentials);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();

    let requestbody = {
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password,
    };



    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        headers: {},
        url: "http://localhost:8081/authenticate",
        data: requestbody,
      });

      console.log("credentials for login = ", credentials);
      console.log("response from api = ", response);
      if (response.status === 200){
        localStorage.setItem("authToken", response.data);
        router.push("/allcoupons");
      }
      else
        alert("invalid credentials")
    } catch (error) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowAlert(true)
      }, 2000);
        setShowAlert(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`min-h-screen p-4 xl:p-28 banner ${reverse ? "bg-white" : "bg-primary"
        }`}
    >
      .
      .
      .
      .
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**home.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Footer from "./components/footer";
import { Alert } from "flowbite-react";
import axios from "axios";



const Allcoupons = ({ datafromAPI }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  //console.log("datafromAPI in components = ", datafromAPI.coupons)
  let data = datafromAPI.coupons;
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [showstatusModal, setshowstatusModal] = useState(false);
  const [detailComponent, setDetailComponent] = useState({}); //state of whole item for details population
  const [statusComponent, setStatusComponent] = useState({ couponCode: "", status: "" });
  const [newStatus, setNewStatus] = useState("");
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState("");


  //I am using this 
  setAuthToken(localStorage.getItem("authToken"));


  
  return (
    <>
      <section className={`text-gray-600 body-font ${(showModal || showstatusModal) ? "bg-slate-800/10" : ""} banner02 fadeRightMini`}>
        <div className="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-col text-center w-full mb-20">
           .
          .
          .

          {/* table */}

          <div className="lg:w-10/12 w-full mx-auto overflow-auto">
            <table className="table-auto w-full text-center whitespace-no-wrap">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  .
                  .
                  .
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {
                  
                  data.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        .
                        . 
                        .
                        .
                      )
                   })
                  }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};


export async function getServerSideProps() {
  
  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/couponstore/v1.0/coupons`, {
    //authtoken not acessible here
    headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`}
  })
  const datafromAPI = res.data
  //console.log("data from API server = ",datafromAPI);

  return { props: { datafromAPI } }
}

export default Allcoupons;
```

### How can I send this authtoken to the home  (`/allcoupons`)  page after logged in successfully in Nextjs?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the initial value from the localStorage.

```
const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(localStorage.get("authToken"));
```

Calling `setAuthToken`, makes the component to re-render infinitely. You can alternatively use `useEffect` for it.

Comment: But its still not accessible in `getServerSideProps()`

Answer (score 0):

Next-auth supports credential login so that you can log in from any API using username/email and password or whatever, this way you set up the token and user in the session, and then you can easily get your token in the getServerSideProps.

In your case, If you check nextjs documentation [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) it only accepts context in getServerSideProps, now context has some predefined values and one of them is **"req"** and it means "The HTTP IncomingMessage object", I'm not much aware of it, but I guess you can try using it to get the token value from cookies. I'm not sure and pardon me if I'm wrong.